# How to make all my radio/checkbox line up?

Tags: html, css

I want to make all my radio in #frequent and the checkbox in #player in a straight line like I did in the #gender, but without the need to give every label and input a separate div. How can I do it?

My [codepen](https://codepen.io/nadav-himmelfarb/pen/BxVYzv) and a part of my code:

In #gender:

```
  <div id="gender">
        <div class="gm">
        <label for="male"> Male  </label>
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" class="rad" >
        </div>
<div class="gf">
        <label for="female"> Female </label>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" class="rad" >
  </div>
```

And for example,

```
 <div id="frequent">
        <legend> How Frequent Do You Listen To Music </legend>
        <label for="aday">All day 
    <input type="radio" id="aday" name="frequent" class="rad">
   </label>

        <label for="eday">Every day
    <input type="radio" id="eday" name="frequent" class="rad">
   </label>
        <label for="oday">Every other day
    <input type="radio" id="oday" name="frequent" class="rad">
   </label>
        <label for="party">I'm a party person
    <input type="radio" id="party" name="frequent" class="rad">
   </label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give the following styles then it will be exactly like the gender

```
#frequent label {
    width: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

#player label {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 50%;
}

#player input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-right: 0;
}

#player input {
    flex: none;
}
```

you can also check the [codepen](https://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/erxgxm)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'm curious, why did you gave #player input - flex none ? because I don't see any change without it

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text in label in a span and then use the following css

HTML

```
<label for="saxophone">  <span>Saxophone </span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="saxophone" class="chk">
</label>
```

CSS

```
label > span {
    min-width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```